# Como faço para chegar em nK pontos de reputação?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Já vi no SO gringo que muitas pessoas possuem ranking >= 1000 * nK de reputação.

Como é possível chegar em uma pontuação tão alta?

Comment: Lembre-se que pra conseguir isso, sua contribuição pro site deve ser um "investimento a longo prazo". Sua pergunta / resposta boa pode não render 100 Upvotes hoje, mas pode render 2 hoje, 3 amanhã, e 5 no outro dia...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

O que dá mais pontos no site é **responder** (10 pontos por voto a favor, e mais 15 se a resposta for aceita).

Em segundo lugar, **perguntar** (5 pontos por voto a favor, e mais 2 se aceitar uma resposta).

Depois, **sugerir edições** (+2 por sugestão aprovada).

Portanto, participe do site, **postando perguntas e respostas de qualidade**, e sua pontuação vai aumentar.

Comment: So lembrando que respondendo coisas que já foram respondidas por outros usuários podem levar a receber votos contra, então sua reputação cairia. E votos contra geralmente chamam mais votos contra.

Comment: @VitorCanova Se a resposta for melhor que as existentes, deve ganhar votos a favor. Por isso eu coloquei em negrito "perguntas e respostas de qualidade".

Comment: Com certeza. Só falei porque em outros SE acontece muito de alguém vir 3 meses depois e postas a mesma resposta de algéum que já estava lá.

Comment: Ah, e desculpa ter colado errado o texto dessa questão na minha pergunta que você editou. Muitas coisas ao mesmo tempo, uma só cabeça. Pode deletar esse comentário depois de ler. ;)

Comment: Sem problema, @VitorCanova, não precisa se desculpar. Aqui é assim mesmo, um vai melhorando o trabalho do outro. Isso é bem legal na plataforma.

Comment: @VitorCanova votar negativamente em uma resposta apenas porque outra resposta foi considerada correta é considerada péssima prática no SO. Existem tópicos e tópicos no meta do SO "matriz" sobre isso.

Comment: @Renan por isso o "...podem levar a receber votos contra..". Já aconteceu comigo no SO. Mas no caso eu e outro usuários criamos ao mesmo tempo, ele salvou antes e recebeu up. Depois me deram down ;)

Answer (score 11):

Não existe fórmula mágica. É tudo questão de dedicação e escrever conteúdo de qualidade.

Como o **@bfavaretto** respondeu, postar respostas é o que dá mais reputação em termos de votos positivos e respostas aceitas.

Vale notar que há um limite de 200 reputação/dia obtida através de votos positivos (reputação obtida através de respostas aceitas não fazem parte deste limite).

Pessoalmente, quando entrei também me perguntava como os "gringos" tinham tanta reputação, mas após um ano e meio frequentando o Stack Overflow internacional já alcancei a marca de >20k reputação. `=]`
<sub>*(o que não é nem metade da reputação do grande bfavaretto, mas estou feliz em ter todos privilégios de moderação lá)*</sub>

E claro, o Stack Overflow internacional recebe cerca de 8 mil perguntas por dia (se não me falha a memória), enquanto o nosso Stack Overflow em Português anda em um ritmo bem mais lento -- ainda não é possível abrir 50 questões da sua linguagem de preferência postadas nas últimas 6 horas e escolher quais responder, o que torna obter reputação através de respostas um tanto mais difícil no momento.

Comment: Concordo. Mas mesmo com poucas perguntas, se alguém tiver conhecimento razoável em alguma tecnologia top, dá para conseguir mais 200 pontos por dia aqui, mesmo agora, e chegar nos 20K em 4 meses :) Não é tão fácil mas é possível. Curiosamente era mais fácil no private beta. Era comum termos post com mais de 10 votos, agora é raro. As pessoas precisam votar mais. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente

Comment: já tinha lido seu post @bigown, muito bem escrito. `=]` Obrigado pela parte histórica, eu tinha me inscrito na proposta da Area51 muito antes do private beta mas pelo jeito acabei não vendo o e-mail de quando o private beta começou. `:(` Bom, não adianta chorar pelo leite derramado, vou correr atrás do tempo perdido quando eu tiver um pouco mais de tempo livre. `=]`

Comment: Muitas pessoas não viram, até abri pergunta aqui sobre isso. Não sei o que aconteceu. Se foi pego como spam ou outro problema, mas recebi relatos que o e-mail não chegou. Se te conhecesse, teria mandado convite pessoal para entrar no private.

Comment: @bigown Não se preocupe, eu sou meio descuidado com os meus e-mails mesmo, aah acabei de achá-lo na inbox do meu e-mail alternativo, este foi falha minha mesmo. `=]`

Comment: Obrigado pelo "grande bfavaretto" :)

Comment: @bfavaretto nada menos do que merecido, afinal suas respostas no SO em inglês são ótimas. Agora vou ter menos trabalho para te stalkear vendo que estás em toda parte do SOePT. `:P`